# Pass parameters into an email

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I have User and Admin, when users publish a post, all the admin receive a mail to be informed. I would like to pass parameters like the title of the post or the name of the user who published the post. At the moment, I'm just able to pass the name of the receiver and this is not what I want. Here is what I've done so far

**Model method**

```
after_create :send_email_to_admins
def send_email_to_admins
  group_admin = UserManager::Group.where("name = ?", "Administrateur").first
  User.all.each do |user|
    if UserManager::Tree.get_default.is_in_group(user,group_admin)
      AdminMailer.notification_mail(user).deliver_now  
    end
  end
end
```

**Mailer method**

```
def notification_mail(user)
  @user = user
  mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Publication boite à idées')
end
```

How can I do to get parameters of the post and pass them into the e-mail ?

Comment: Which class is your "model method" in?

Comment: It's the post which user publish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this (slightly pseudo-code-y as you don't explain your schema)

```
#in Post model
after_create :deliver_email_notifications

def deliver_email_notifications
  Admin.all.each do |admin|
    Mailer.deliver_post_notification(self,admin)
  end
end

#in Mailer

def post_notification(post, admin)
  #send an email to admin.email, using a template which has some information about the post
end
```

Comment: Tried your code but it didn't work, "post" is undefined. The thing that I don't understand is, how to pass my post value into 'post_notification'

Comment: Just pass the post object, as i'm doing above.